# Intermittent inaccessible SYSVOL

Tags: sysvol

I'm having a weird issue, when running gpupdate on a computer. It comes down to SYSVOL not being accessible. Client: Windows 10 buid 1709 / 16299.125

Situation: 2 domain controllers (Windows Server 2012 R2).
- browse to \dc01\sysvol : works
- browse to \dc02\sysvol : works
- browse to \intranet\sysvol : works

Works intermittently (as in, I don't change anything, don't reboot, just try again at later points):
- browse to \intranet.izegem.be\sysvol -> sysvol folder is visible but prompts credentials, even Domain Admin doesn't work
- browse to \\sysvol -> sysvol folder is visible but prompts credentials, even Domain Admin doesn't work
- browse to \\sysvol -> sysvol folder is visible but prompts credentials, even Domain Admin doesn't work

What could I check? Nothing weird visible when I check dcdiag /v

**Update**: for future reference, it seems to be a Windows bug: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a20e3f6-728a-4aa9-831a-6133f446ea08/gpos-do-not-apply-on-windows-10-enterprise-x64?forum=winserverGP

Strangely enough, even Microsoft comes to this conclusion.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/leesteve/2017/08/09/demystifying-the-unc-hardening-dilemma/

Domain Forest Level is now 2012R2 as well. No idea what the fix is besides those registry-keys, which seem to be a workaround/disabling.